# Automation with Sharepoint 2010

Tags: application-pages

I have a scenario where I need to get the job listings from a feed(which will give me the list of jobs in XML file) and display it in a sharepoint page. I will have a the daily feeds coming in. Please let me know how do I achive this.

Answer (score 0):

Several options that come to mind. You can use an RSS web part, an XML viewer web part, create your own dataview web part, create a visual web part.

Comment: Is it possible to have a page like instead of a web part please?

Comment: A dataview web part on a page will just grab the XML and process it using XSLT resulting in your desired html output. Your question is rather vague and I gave you a variety of options.